# jQuery wrap vaguely. How to get correct html structure of result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use jQuery wrap and want to achieve result html structure like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="squares"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="target">
        <span id="test">some content<span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is me code:

```
$("#test").wrap('<table><tr><td class="squares"></td></tr><tr><td class="target"></td></tr><table>');
```

But the result is very different:

```
<table><tr><td class="squares"><span id="test">some content<span>
</span></span></td></tr><tr><td class="target"></td></tr></table>
```

How can I get the desired behavior? Here is jsfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/y6L7n6Lj/

Comment: From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) (emphasis mine): *The `.wrap()` function can take any string or object that could be passed to the `$()` factory function to specify a DOM structure. This structure may be nested several levels deep,* ***but should contain only one inmost element.***

Comment: How should jquery know where to wrap in all that html?

Comment: `<span id="test">some content<span>` should be `<span id="test">some content</span>`  span close tag

Comment: @Cattla: Actually he has nested spans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#test").wrap('<table border="1"><tr><td class="target"></td></tr><table>')
    .closest("table")
    .prepend('<tr><td class="squares">squares</td></tr>');
```

Explanation:

- Wrap your test span in a HTML structre with only one innnermost element, as pointed out by Frederic in the comments
- Traverse up your newly-wrapped structure to find the table at the top
- Prepend the extra `<tr>` into this table

Update to your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/y6L7n6Lj/2/

Note that I've added a couple of things just to make the results more obvious in the fiddle:

1. table borders
2. The text 'square'

You'll want to remove these for your version :-)